# Long running PHP process stuck in loop - strace output included

Tags: php, c, linux, strace

I have a long running PHP process, that sometimes hangs in a loop. This is the strace output, but I don't know what it means:

```
nanosleep({1, 0}, {1, 0})               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0}, {1, 0})               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0}, {1, 0})               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0},  <unfinished ...>
```

The calls above keep looping indefinitely, and the process doesn't recover. What do the calls above mean?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell from this, can you post some of the PHP code that's hanging?

Comment: It's a 1700 line procedural code, I was hoping the strace output could be translated so I can understand what php could matches the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was wrong. It waits infinitely:

```
// Ignore SIGCHLD (Child process stopped or terminated)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
// Set handler to SIGCHLD to default (i.e. ignore)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
// Un-ignore SIGCHLD
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
// Sleep for a second
nanosleep({1, 0}, {1, 0}) = 0
```

I have no idea why you would install signal handlers in a loop, but this is the behavior caused by the following php code:

```
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

I cannot imagine a reason why you would call sleep for non-debugging purposes in php, so look for any invocations of `sleep`, `usleep` or `time_nanosleep`.

Comment: Updated. `sleep`, `usleep`, or `time_nanosleep` is probably the keyword.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa If it's legally possible, could you elaborate a little bit on why some php code called `sleep` in a loop? (Just for my informal list of common or not-so-common programming errors, and if you don't mind and it's not too compicated)

Comment: `while ( ! $running ) { doYourThing(); sleep(1); }` - `$running` is set to `false` by `doYourThing` when it has finished executing and is ready to start again.